# Form recognizer model detecting irrelevant data in handwritten form

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, azure-form-recognizer, azure-ai

Trained some handwritten pdf forms through FOTT but model is not recognizing the letter correctly, taking irrelevant characters: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YxRd.jpg

Comment: It depends on many factors like numbers of documents trained, quality of document and you can trained more data for better accuracy also try out without handwritten also!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest GA version of Form Recognizer located here - https://formrecognizer.appliedai.azure.com/studio
API version 2022-08-31 ?
If you can share the document with Form Recognizer Contact Us formrecog_contact@microsoft.com we can look into this and assist.